# Beamer note page: Reduce left margin

Tags: beamer, margins

I am using the beamer notes, but to my mind, the left margin is a bit too large since it reduces the usable space significantly. Is it possible to reduce this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[compact]
\setbeameroption{second mode text on second screen=left}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}
\begin{frame}{bla}
Some text.
\note[item]{This is a note item}
\note{only text note}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here a picture with the margin I mean marked in red
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the commands `\AtBeginNote` and `\AtEndNote` to modify this behavior.

For normal notes you can add some negative space at the beginning, e.g. `\hspace*{-10pt}`, while for the others you have to modify `itemize`-specific lengths. For example you can issue a `\addtolength\leftmargini{-10pt}` at the beginning and `\addtolength\leftmargini{10pt}` at the end so to restore the normal behavior.

In other words, you can add the following lines to achieve what you want

```
\AtBeginNote{\hspace*{-10pt}\addtolength\leftmargini{-10pt}}
\AtEndNote{\addtolength\leftmargini{10pt}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[compact]
\setbeameroption{second mode text on second screen=left}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}
\section{bla}
\begin{frame}{bla}
Some text.
\note[item]{This is a note item}
\note{only text note}
\end{frame}

\AtBeginNote{\hspace*{-10pt}\addtolength\leftmargini{-10pt}}
\AtEndNote{\addtolength\leftmargini{10pt}}

\section{bla}
\begin{frame}{bla}
Some text.
\note[item]{This is a note item}
\note{only text note}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can notice the difference in consecutive frames:

[image]

Of course, in your document, place those two lines at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I think `\addtolength\leftmargini{-10pt}´ applies to all itemize environments also on normal slides right? Is there any way to apply it only to the note pages?

Comment: @bonanza Answer edited. Now they apply only to notes and not to all `itemize` environments.

Comment: @bonanza Does it work fine now?

Comment: thanks for your work! in the MWE it works, but unfortunately in my real case, I am using "\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5cm}}" in the preamble and this seems to break it again. Do have a guess why? thanks!!

Comment: @bonanza Replacing that line with `\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\addtolength\leftmargini{-7.5pt}}` should work.